# How can I access the data in the returned json in c#?

Tags: c#, json, parsing

I have a method `abc()` returning:

```
return Json(new { success = false, responseText = "Input-Values not valid" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

I use this method in an ajax-call (in javascript) as well as in another method in the same class (in c#).
In the ajax-call, I can check if success=true.

**How can I do that in c#? Do I have to parse it there?**

What I want to do is sth like:

```
public ActionResult xyz(string x, string y) { 
   ActionResult result= this.abc();
   //if result.success==false than get responseText and do something
}
```

Comment: I would refactor the code so both `abc` and `xyz` have access to the actual data, rather than the json action result.

Comment: But then I have code duplication because I would copy the code in abc() into xyz.

Comment: In order to avoid the code duplication, I could make a third method containing the code of abc() without returning an ActionResult. Than both methods can use it for their own purposes but don't know if that's a good solution @WiktorZychla

Comment: you first misunderstood the recommendation - yes, a third method called from the two is the obvious choice here.

Answer (score 1):

Have 2 functions

```
private MyObject abc()
{
    //your going to have to create a MyObject class
    return new MyObject(){ success = false, responseText = "Input-Values not valid" };
}

public ActionResult ABC()
{
    return Json(this.abc());
}
```

Then its just:

```
public ActionResult xyz(string x, string y) { 
   MyObject result= this.abc();
   if (result.success){

  }
}
```

It'd be good practice to move `private MyObject abc()` into a new logic class. This will help keep your controller "skinny".

You don't seem to understand methods in C# very well. I'd suggets you do some more reading up on the subject, e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/methods

Comment: I get 'object does not contain a definition for 'responseText' ' for doing 

    private Object abc().

What is a valid type for that return object?

Comment: whatever your object is? Your using a anonymous type in your code, your going to have to create a class and return that, hence `MyObject`

Comment: success is a boolean, responseText is a string. There is no other object to be returned from the private abc() class @Liam

Comment: You could use a tuple rather than explicitly declaring a new class, which would not be a very interesting one (`(bool success, string responseText)`). Of course, you have to then "parse" this tuple before making a JSON result out of it.